# Lack of closure as a theme in the works of Isaac Bashevis Singer

Tags: yiddish-language, isaac-bashevis-singer, theme

While reading the works of Isaac Bashevis Singer over the past couple months, I've gotten the impression that Singer will often - especially in short stories - leave you with a sense that not everything has been resolved, and that crucial developments within the story never received closure.

For instance, the [ending of "Pigeons"](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/21892/58) leaves you with a sense of something missing; there's no closure with the killers of the professor.

In "The Cafeteria", a major part of the story, Hitler being spotted in a restaurant, is never explained or resolved.

In "The Mentor", the story ends with a statement of despair and nothing is resolved.

Aside from these examples, somebody I spoke to mentioned that a lack of closure in Singer stories had come up while studying literature at [Bar-Ilan](https://www.biu.ac.il/en), although they don't recall enough to comment on it.

Is a lack of closure a consistent theme throughout Singer's works? What could be behind this, if so?

Comment: This sounds like a very open-ended question.

Comment: I don't quite agree @Mary: it seems to me specific evidence could be marshalled from the text and supporting literature to answer this in a specific way.